# receiving JSON response (android)

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to send a JSON with the information email address, first and last names and expecting a response from the server to say {status: "Created"} or {status: "Resend"} and depending on the answer there would be a pop up message. I was wondering what I use to extract the information from the status class. Thanks!
Here is my code to accept

```
protected void sendJson(final String email, final String firstN,
        final String lastN) {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare(); // For Preparing Message Pool for the child
                                // Thread
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(),
                    10000); // Timeout Limit
            HttpResponse response;
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            try {

                // post in the url


                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                        "https://iphone-radar.com/accounts");
                json.put("email_address", email);
                json.put("first_name", firstN);
                json.put("last_name", lastN);
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity("JSON: "
                        + json.toString());
                se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                        "application/json"));
                post.setEntity(se);
                response = client.execute(post);
                /* Checking response */
                if (response != null) {
                    String str = response.getEntity().toString();
                    if (str.equals("Created")) {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateAccount.this)
                                .setTitle("Account Creation Successful")
                                .setMessage(
                                        "An activation code has been sent to you. Please check your SPAM folder if you do not receive your activation code email")
                                .setNeutralButton("OK", null).show();
                    } else if(str.equals("Resend")) {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateAccount.this)
                                .setTitle("Code Resent")
                                .setMessage(
                                        "Your activation code has been resent to your email.\n\nIf you are not receiving your activation code, our email is being blocked. Please email us at 'help@iphone-tracker.net' and we will manually send you a code.")
                                .setNeutralButton("OK", null).show();
                    }


                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert the response to a string, then create a [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html). You can then just access the JSON object's properties. Try this:

```
org.json.JSONObject obj = new org.json.JSONObject(org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
                    if ("Created".equals(obj.getString("status"))) {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateAccount.this)
                                .setTitle("Account Creation Successful")
                                .setMessage(
                                        "An activation code has been sent to you. Please check your SPAM folder if you do not receive your activation code email")
                                .setNeutralButton("OK", null).show();
                    } else if("Resend".equals(obj.getString("status"))) {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateAccount.this)
                                .setTitle("Code Resent")
                                .setMessage(
                                        "Your activation code has been resent to your email.\n\nIf you are not receiving your activation code, our email is being blocked. Please email us at 'help@iphone-tracker.net' and we will manually send you a code.")
                                .setNeutralButton("OK", null).show();
                    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however when I put it through the debugger the line org.json.JSONObject obj = new org.json.JSONObject(org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())); sends me to catch (Exception e)  Is there something wrong with me or with the server? Thanks again

Comment: What Exception does it give? use `android.util.Log.v("EXCEPTION","["+e.getMessage()+"]", e);` to print out the entire exception in the log. Either the response's entity is null (which is probably the server) or there is some conversion error in the `EntityUtils.toString` method.

Comment: It says [Value <html> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject]  does this mean I'm using the wrong website? Thanks again

Comment: It means that the return value is not JSON: your server is not sending back the expected JSON string, so the parse is failing. Verify that your server is correctly responding.

Comment: Im new to dealing with JSONs, is there a simple way to see what is being returned to me? (e.g. to check the value of a string I would look at the variables table)

Comment: You can just do `android.util.Log.v("TAG", org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()))` to see what you're receiving before you try and parse it.

Comment: I see, the server is responding with it's html code instead of the expected result.